# Getting error while declaring and calling view in Sencha Touch MVC framework.

Tags: android, model-view-controller, sencha-touch

I am new to sencha touch mvc framework and i am using version1.1.1 on android os.I have created controller and view in my demo app.I am getting error in my app.js and viewport.js.

Here's **app.js**:-

```
Ext.regApplication({
    name: 'MyApp',
    defaultUrl: 'Home/index',
    launch: function()
    {
        this.viewport = new MyApp.view.viewport();
    },
});
```

and here's **viewport.js**:-

```
MyApp.view.viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{

   fullscreen: 'true',
   layout: 'card',
   cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
   dockedItems: [
   {
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    title: 'MvcTouch',
   },
   ],
});
```

Now my problem is that when i run my app with above pieces of codes i am getting the following errors.

**1)** `TypeError: Result of expression 'MyApp.view' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/app/view/viewport.js:9`

**2)** `TypeError: Result of expression 'MyApp.view' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/app/app.js:6`

I write the code according to the standards explained [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/video/class-system) by **Sencha**'s core developer .But when i change the line

**MyApp.view.viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{**

to

**viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{**   in viewport.js

and change the line

**this.viewport = new MyApp.view.viewport();**

to

**this.viewport = new viewport();** in app.js

the app works well.Now I dont understand about the code that it works well when i am not using standard conventions of sencha and does not work when i used the standard convention.
Can anybody tell me what's happening here.Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sencha Touch 1.1.1, the app views are defined with "views" not "view". So, try this:

MyApp.**views**.viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{

This should work fine then.

Comment: yes, its just a folder and the mapping isn't there for Sencha Touch 1.1.1 . But in Sencha Touch 2.0 you will see that the folders and the class names are mapped accurately.